# JSP Table Sort Not Working

Tags: jsp, sorting, displaytag

I have the following code for a table in jsp using tags which seems very straightforward. However, for some odd reason, the sort I am using is not working at all, and causing all sorts of head-ache to me.

The jsp table code:

```
<display:table name="searchResult.FormList" class="display" id="forms" keepStatus="true"
export="true" pagesize="500" sort="list" defaultSort="2" defaultOrder="ascending"
requestURI="searchResult.htm?paging=true">

<display:column title="Select"><input type="checkbox" name="selForm" value="${forms.objectId}"/>"/></display:column>

<display:column title="Form Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"><a href="javascript:onclick=
downloadForm('${session.userId}','${forms.objectId}','${forms.objectName}'/></a>
<c:out value="${forms.objectName}"/></display:column>
```

Now, given the table and columns, I would expect the table results to be sorted by the second column - which displays the objectName from the resulting object forms. However, this is not the case. Somehow the sorting does not work at all. The default sorting is haphazard (A,D,E,B,C instead of A,B,C,D,E), and when we try to manually sort it from the column, the sorting is not correct again. The forms.objectName always has alphabets.

I tried a couple of things. One of them was (for the second column, everything else the same):

```
<display:column property="objectName" title="Form Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
```

When I do this, the table populates, and not-surprisingly, the table is sorted perfectly by this second column (A,B,C,D,E as expected). However, the problem with this is that these do not have the hyperlinks, hence I can not use this.

Another thing I tried was, with the second column:

```
<display:column property="objectName" title="Form Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" href="javascript:onclick=
downloadForm('${session.userId}','${forms.objectId}','${forms.objectName}')"/>
```

Again, this sorts the table perfectly by this second column (A,B,C,D,E). However, the parameters on the downloadForm method are from the last row of the table i.e. for example, if there are 10 rows in the search table, the second column link would get the forms.objectId & forms.objectName from the last row on all 10 rows. Hence, I can not use this as well.

I hope my problem is clear to you. Any help is really appreciated. Let me know if you require further explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I found out one thing. In the first set of the codes above (with bad sorting), the system is sorting by the form.objectId which is in a href. Why is that happening? Why is not it sorting by form.objectName instead?

Answer (score 0):

Could try with :

```
<display:column title="Form Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" sortName="objectName">
   <a href="javascript:onclick=downloadForm('${session.userId}','${forms.objectId}','${forms.objectName}'/></a>
   <c:out value="${forms.objectName}"/>
<display:column>
```

Exactly the same as the first code you paste but adding the attribute `sortName="objectName"` to your `display:column`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to specify the sortProperty as displayTag cannot magically work out that you wish to sort on the 'name' property.

From the Tag Library Reference documentation:

> **sortProperty**: name of the property in the bean specified in the parent table tag (via the "name" attribute) which will be used to sort
>   values in the column. **This can be used when the column body is filled
>   or a decorator is used and column should sort on undecorated values**.

```
<display:column title="Form Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" sortProperty="name" />
```